# How can I improve this Python / Xonsh script (converted from bash)?

Tags: shell-script, python3, xonsh

I'm starting to learn xonsh and Python. I want to use Python mainly for shell scripting and I want to replace many existing small to medium bash scripts.

I started with the bash script given below (with some comments added). I manually converted it into Python (shown further below). **Please point out where my Python can be improved or made more concise.**

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line;
do
  echo $line | grep '^Path=' >/dev/null 2>&1
  if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then \
    path=~/.mozilla/firefox/$(echo $line | sed 's/^Path=//')/user.js; #open the user.js file for each profile
    if [[ -f ${path} ]]; then \
      echo "Processing: path: ${path}";
      grep 'browser.ctrlTab.sortByRecentlyUsed' ${path} >/dev/null 2>&1 #check if this property already exists
      if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then \
        echo 'user_pref("browser.ctrlTab.sortByRecentlyUsed", true);' >> ${path}; #did not exist, so append it to end of file
      else
        sed -i 's/browser.ctrlTab.sortByRecentlyUsed",.*false/browser.ctrlTab.sortByRecentlyUsed", true/' ${path} #did exist, so change it to desired value if needed
      fi
      echo "updated ctrlTab.sortByRecentlyUsed for $path"

      grep 'browser.tabs.loadBookmarksInTabs' ${path} >/dev/null 2>&1
      if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then \
        echo 'user_pref("browser.tabs.loadBookmarksInTabs", false);' >> ${path};
      else
        sed -i 's/browser.tabs.loadBookmarksInTabs",.*true/browser.tabs.loadBookmarksInTabs", false/' ${path}
      fi
      echo "updated loadBookmarksInTabs for $path"

    fi
  fi
done < ~/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini #read this file to find the path to all profiles
```

I have a working Python solution now, but it seems a lot more complicated that I expected. My goal is to be able to write short & quick solutions for situations like this one. At this time I don't expect to be writing large Python programs. I do hope to use xonsh extensively once I learn enough. I can obviously get rid of the print statements I included for my learning. Other than that, how can my solution shown below be improved or shortened?

In particular, I had intended to use [pysed](https://pypi.org/project/pysed/) and Python's [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input) but I wasn't able to achieve a working solution with those.

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import re

trgt_file='user.js'
myuser='mountainx'
base_path = Path('/home/' myuser '/.mozilla/firefox')
if not base_path.is_dir():
  print("ERROR:", base_path, "does not exist.")
  # exit()
else:
  print("OK: processing", base_path)

ini_path = Path(base_path / 'profiles.ini')
if not ini_path.is_file():
  print("ERROR:", ini_path, "cannot be opened.")
  # exit()
else:
  print("OK: opening", ini_path)

match_ctrltab = False
match_bookmark_found = False
pro_path_re = re.compile(r'^Path=(\w+)$')
ctrltab_sort_regex = re.compile(r'^/*?user_pref\("browser\.ctrlTab\.sortByRecentlyUsed.*$', re.M)
ctrltab_sort_repls = 'user_pref("browser.ctrlTab.sortByRecentlyUsed", true);'
bookmark_open_regex = re.compile(r'^/*?user_pref\("browser\.tabs\.loadBookmarksInTabs.*$', re.M)
bookmark_open_repls = 'user_pref("browser.tabs.loadBookmarksInTabs", false);'
with open(ini_path, "r") as profiles_ini:
  for any_line in profiles_ini:
    m_path = pro_path_re.match(any_line)
    if not m_path is None:
      p_path = m_path.group(1)
      print("p_path:", p_path)
      profile_path = Path(base_path / p_path)
      print("profile_path:", profile_path)
      if profile_path.is_dir():
        print("The profile path is", profile_path)
        user_js_path = Path(profile_path / trgt_file)
        if Path(user_js_path).is_file():
          print("OK: valid file:", user_js_path)
          with open(user_js_path, 'r+') as file_userjs:
            #read the file contents
            file_contents = file_userjs.read()
            match_ctrltab = ctrltab_sort_regex.search(file_contents)
            if match_ctrltab is None:
              file_contents = file_contents + '\n' + ctrltab_sort_repls
              print('No match: added line to end of file contents:', ctrltab_sort_repls)
            else:
              file_contents = ctrltab_sort_regex.sub(ctrltab_sort_repls, file_contents)
              print('Match found. Replaced line in file for ctrltab_sort')

            match_bookmark = bookmark_open_regex.search(file_contents)
            if match_bookmark is None:
              file_contents = file_contents + '\n' + bookmark_open_repls
              print('No match: added line to end of file contents:', bookmark_open_repls)
            else:
              file_contents = bookmark_open_regex.sub(bookmark_open_repls, file_contents)
              print('Match found. Replaced line for bookmark_open_regex')
            file_userjs.seek(0)
            file_userjs.truncate()
            file_userjs.write(file_contents)
        else:
          print("SKIPPED: invalid file:", user_js_path)
```

Here is some date I am testing it against. The general solution should work against any Firefox user.js or prefs.js file.

```
file_contents = """
user_pref("media.gmp-gmpopenh264.abi", "x86_64-gcc3");
user_pref("media.gmp-gmpopenh264.autoupdate", false);
user_pref("media.gmp-gmpopenh264.enabled", false);
user_pref("media.gmp-gmpopenh264.lastUpdate", 1571947201);
user_pref("media.gmp-gmpopenh264.version", "1.8.1");
user_pref("browser.ctrlTab.sortByRecentlyUsed",false);
//user_pref("browser.ctrlTab.sortByRecentlyUsed", true);"""
```

Comment: grep and sed are external tools, not bash. It's highly unlikely bash script can converted into other script language automatically (except for pure plain bash maybe)

Comment: I am not asking about automatically converting a bash script into another language. I am asking for feedback to help me improve my Python & xonsh skills.

Comment: sorry *convert* scripts sounded bit misleading to me. in german I would say *(re)writing* scripts

Comment: I'm learning Python and xonsh. My goal is to convert many bash scripts into Python. I plan to do it manually myself. My question could have been titled: Seeking feedback to improve my xonsh/Python skills for writing short shell scripts. So how can my Python be improved?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the best I have come up with on my own so far.

I wrote two functions and saved them in a directory named modtest (and saved the file as ffutils.py).
`touch modtest/__init__.py`
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33770042 for more on that.

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import re

def find_profile_dirs(user=None, debug=False):
  profiles = []
  if user is None:
    base_path = Path('~/.mozilla/firefox').expanduser()
  else:
    base_path = Path('/home') / user / '.mozilla/firefox'
  if not base_path.is_dir():
    print("ERROR:", base_path, "does not exist.")
  elif debug:
    print("OK: processing", base_path)
  ini_path = Path(base_path / 'profiles.ini')
  if not ini_path.is_file():
    print("ERROR:", ini_path, "cannot be opened.")
  elif debug:
    print("OK: opening", ini_path)
  pro_path_re = re.compile(r'^Path=(\w+)$')
  with open(ini_path, "r") as profiles_ini:
    for any_line in profiles_ini:
      m_path = pro_path_re.match(any_line)
      if not m_path is None:
        p_path = m_path.group(1)
        if debug:
          print("p_path:", p_path)
        profile_path = Path(base_path / p_path)
        if debug:
          print("profile_path:", profile_path)
        if profile_path.is_dir():
          profiles.append(profile_path)
          print("The profile path is", profile_path)
  return profiles


# profiles_paths is a list of Paths of all Firefox profiles to process
def process_userjs(searchExp, replaceExp, profiles_paths, debug=False):
  match_result = None
  search_regex = re.compile(searchExp, re.M)

  trgt_file='user.js'
  for profile_path in profiles_paths:
    user_js_path = Path(profile_path / trgt_file)
    if Path(user_js_path).is_file():
      if debug:
        print("OK: valid file:", user_js_path)
      with open(user_js_path, 'r+') as file_userjs:
        file_contents = file_userjs.read()
        match_result = search_regex.search(file_contents)
        if match_result is None:
          file_contents = file_contents + '\n' + replaceExp
          if debug:
            print('No match: added new line to end of file contents:', replaceExp)
        else:
          file_contents = search_regex.sub(replaceExp, file_contents)
          if debug:
            print('Match found. Modified existing line in file.')

        file_userjs.seek(0)
        file_userjs.truncate()
        file_userjs.write(file_contents)
    elif debug:
      print("SKIPPED: invalid file:", user_js_path)
```

Then I used the functions like this:

```
import sys
sys.path = ['/path/to/parent/of/modtest'] + sys.path # if needed
from modtest import ffutils

my_profiles = ffutils.find_profile_dirs()

srchexp = r'^/*?user_pref\("browser\.ctrlTab\.sortByRecentlyUsed.*$'
replexp = 'user_pref("browser.ctrlTab.sortByRecentlyUsed", true);'
ffutils.process_userjs(srchexp, replexp, my_profiles, True)
```

Of course, I can repeat it with other search & replace strings.

I'm sure there are still many ways to improve this. I'll accept other answers, but I'm putting my own answer here in case there are no others offered.

There are a few assumptions in my code. A big one is that it assumes all Firefox profile paths are relative. If that isn't a valid assumption, a little more processing on profiles.ini is needed.